# Bootstrap Dropdown Hover Text Color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've done a crap ton of research into how I can accomplish this, but I can't find anything solid or anything that I can properly understand.

I want to override the Bootstrap Dropdown hover color. Not the Dropdown menu, the actual Dropdown button itself. By default, the text color is white, and when you hover over it, it's some sort of blue-green color. I want to make the blue-green color to white as well.

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about doing this?

Here's my current code incase you need it:

CSS:

```css
@media {
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;    
    }
    
    .navbar-custom {
        color: #262626;
        background-color: #262626;
    }
    
    .navbar-default {
        color: #262626;
        background-color: #262626;
        border-top: 4px solid red;
    }
    
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
        color: white;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover {
        color: white;
    }
    
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

#navbar {
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```html
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="dropdowns">
                <a class="navbar-brand" id="brand">Traders: </a>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">General <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#medical">Medical</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#utility">Utility</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sorry if I left something out or don't make much sense, currently on some powerful pain meds. This helps me get my mind off the pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try including the *!important* to the style:

```
color: white !important;
```

this is done to override the default styles bootstrap establishes for the elements.

Comment: This worked. I also had to add "a" to the end of the CSS dropdown:hover and now it's purely white. Thank you so much!